# Does @SendToUser in Spring only works when Spring Security is integrated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm getting started with websockets with springboot. So at first I have successfully created a demo chat application, where messages are broadcast-ed to every user. 
Now instead of broadcasting a message to all users, I want to send a message to one particular user, so I stumbled upon @SendToUser annotation. Now, I'm not able to figure out how this annotation will work. My application currently lacks any kind of registration process including Spring Security framework.

Can anyone point to me some good articles regarding this topic, also is it possible to send one to one message with this annotation without implementing Spring Security?

This is what I've done so far :

```
//Controller
@Controller
public class MessageController
{

   @Autowired
   private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

   //This broadcasts to all users
   @MessageMapping("/send")
   @SendTo("/topic/greeting")
   public MessageBean send(MessageBean message)
   {
      message.setDate( ZonedDateTime.now() );
      return message;
   }

   //This is intended to particular user
   @MessageMapping("/message")
   @SendToUser("/topic/greeting")
   public MessageBean processMessage(@Payload MessageBean message)
   {
      message.setDate( ZonedDateTime.now() );
      return message;
   } 
}
```

//WebSocketConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer#configureMessageBroker(org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry)
    */
   @Override
   public void configureMessageBroker( MessageBrokerRegistry config )
   {
      config.enableSimpleBroker( "/topic/", "/queue/" );
      config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes( "/app" );
      config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user"); 
   }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer#registerStompEndpoints(org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry)
    */
   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints( StompEndpointRegistry registry )
   {
      StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration registration = registry.addEndpoint( "/secretum" );
      registration.setHandshakeHandler( new DefaultHandshakeHandler()
      {
         @SuppressWarnings("unused")
         public boolean beforeHandshake( ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler, Map< String, String > attributes )
               throws Exception
         {
            if ( request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest )
            {
               ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = ( ServletServerHttpRequest ) request;
               HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
               attributes.put( "sessionId", session.getId() );
            }
            return true;

         }

      } );
      registration.setAllowedOrigins( "*" ).withSockJS();
   }
}
```

//Client side:

```
var clentModule = angular.module('clentModule', []);

//Main Controller
clentModule.controller('clentController', function($scope) {
    var client;
    $scope.connectAndSubscribe = function()
    {
        var url = "ws://localhost:8080/secretum/websocket";
        client = webstomp.client(url);
        connected = function()
        {
            console.log("connected");
        }

        var headers = {};
        client.connect(headers,function(){
            console.log("successfuly connected");
            var subscription = client.subscribe("/topic/greetings",subscriptionCallback);
        });

        subscriptionCallback = function(data) {
            console.log("subscription data", data);
        }

        //var subscription = client.subscribe("/topic/greetings",subscriptionCallback);
        //console.log(subscription);
    };

    $scope.sendMessage = function()
    {
        //var subscription = client.subscribe("/topic/greetings",subscriptionCallback);
        $scope.message = {};
        $scope.message.sender = "xyz";
        $scope.message.reciever = "abc";
        var sendObject = JSON.stringify($scope.message);
        client.send("/topic/greetings", {priority: 9}, sendObject);
    };

});
```

My question is from client side, how shall I send the request to send a message to particular user, since I've no user information stored in the server. So that is my initial question, does this annotation works without spring security?

Answer (score 0):

@Paras...see this once you will get idea

Use @SendToUser and add "/user/" in front of queue when subscribing (only subscriber side). Rest works magic :-)

Instead of

```
Java Server: @SendTo("/topic/showResult")
```

and

```
JS Client: stompClient.subscribe('/topic/showResult', function(calResult){  ....
```

use:

```
Java Server: @SentToUser("/topic/showResult")
```

and

```
JS Client: stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/showResult', function(calResult){ ....
```

credit to @RS...

and override

> configureClientInboundChannel() method in WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer interface

Comment: Hi @kumar, I've made some edits and included the code snippet of what I've done so far.